# 'Resource Temporarily Unavailable' after POST http request is received - Python

Tags: python, forms, http-post

I am having problem with my server socket. I am making a web server and trying to fill a from a browser. The form HTML script is as shown:

```
<html>
<body bgcolor = black text= white>
<FORM method="post" action="/processData.py">
<P>
<LABEL for="firstname">First name: </LABEL>
<INPUT type="text" id="firstname"><BR>

<LABEL for="lastname">Last name: </LABEL>
<INPUT type="text" id="lastname"><BR>

<LABEL for="email">email: </LABEL>
<INPUT type="text" id="email"><BR>

<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female<BR>

<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
</P>
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to print the entire request on my terminal when a POST request is sent from the browser after hitting 'submit'. when i receive the POST request on my web server, the socket throws a '[Errno 35] Resource Temporarily Unavailable'. I am not closing the connection or anything but somehow i am loosing connection. Here is the code i am using in python to get POST.

```
while not recvIsComplete:
    rcvdStr = fd.recv( 1024 )
    if rcvdStr[0:3] == "GET":
        toGET()

    elif rcvdStr[0:4] == "POST":       
        print rcvdStr
```

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: We'll need to know more about how exactly you're "making a web server". But generally, you get errno 35 (`EAGAIN`) when you try to read from a nonblocking socket but there's no data to read. (It's a bit confusing, because on most POSIX platforms, `EWOULDBLOCK: Operation would block` is the same errno as `EAGAIN: Resource temporarily available`.)

Comment: Also, I can guess that the error is being raised on the line `rcvdStr = fd.recv( 1024 )`, and what the traceback says… but it would be nice to show us so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Also, you may want to check whether `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK` are the some on your platform. (If you're on Windows, don't try to answer that, just say "I'm on Windows.")

Comment: yes the error is occurring on recv(...). Sorry i forgot to mention that earlier. What is the possible solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be correct, but it seems most likely based on the information you've given:

You've written a blocking server—probably each client connection in its own thread (but maybe using processes or greenlets instead, or maybe even just only handling one client at a time). But you're using non-blocking sockets.

The details depend on your exact code and platform, but the most common reason to get this is that you called `recv` on a non-blocking socket with no data on it, and it's returning `EWOULDBLOCK`, and your platform has the same error number for `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK`.

If so, the easy answer is: don't use non-blocking sockets with a blocking server. Either make sure the sockets are in blocking mode, or don't call `recv` on them unless you know there's data (e.g., because `select` just told you so).

You *can* handle non-blocking sockets in a blocking server by `try`ing the `recv` and handling the `EWOULDBLOCK` in some way (e.g., `select` on just that socket and try again, or send a heartbeat/idle packet to make sure the other side is still there, or whatever is appropriate for your design). But usually, that's not what you want to do; you can do something simpler with `settimeout`.